# CSS the borders of my <TD> and <TH> don't meet

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I make the `border-right` of my `<td>` meet with the `border-right` of my `<th>` above it? there is a little gap between them. is there a way to make it extend further down or make the left border of the `<td>` extend further up?

Answer (score 3):

To collapse your borders, use the `border-collapse` property:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

This gets rid of the spacing between your table borders.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind sorry I found it. its cellspacing=0

Comment: **Do not solve a CSS problem with HTML presentational attributes!**

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set [`border-spacing`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html#borderspacing) to `0px` in your CSS.